# fatal error: thread.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

Is there any way to access `thread.h` file .

I am not able to find thread.h header in windows since threading is related to OS.

I tried using pthread.h an external library , but was never able to find thread.h which according to my professor works in solaris.

Comment: "thread.h" is just a filename. You're going to have to tell us what library you're actually trying to find... Also, tag only the language you're actually using. For example, if you're using C++, just include `<thread>` and be done with it; no need for any third-party shenanigans.

Comment: Are you looking for `<threads.h>` or `<pthread.h>`?

Comment: threads.h file is missing in the cygwin library to be precise

Comment: @avinashvp The official header is [`<thread>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ nope i tried using thread it does not work  , unable to build.../src/dining_philo.c:16:18: fatal error: thread: No such file or directory
 #include <thread>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
src/subdir.mk:21: recipe for target 'src/dining_philo.o' failed
make: *** [src/dining_philo.o] Error 1

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have edited my post and  i am using C , does the files differ between c and c++

Comment: @avinashvp Of course. After all, C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: gcc does not support c11 threading as documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status)

Comment: @AlanAu thats why used  Cygwin .. does Cygwin support c11 threading?

Comment: cygwin is not a compiler. I don't actually know much about cygwin but my understanding is that either `gcc` or `minGW` is commonly used for compilation. `minGW` provides a port of `gcc`. So it is highly unlikely either support c11 threading.

Comment: @AlanAu cygwin does the same job of mingw but provides extra features like posix threads which would work in linux.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin

Comment: Well, whoever wrote the code originally must have been using some compiler or other.  Can you find out which one?

Comment: _"cygwin does the same job of mingw"_ Complete nonsense.

Comment: The code is pretty old and the operating system in which the code was executed is solaris. So I did not want to go deep into it

Answer (score 8):

This is an excellent example where tagging a question with "C" and "C++" is highly confusing because the answers are entirely different.

If you are coding in **C++11** or later, then you should

```
#include <thread>
```

and use the `std::thread` class.  You'll be fine.

If you are coding in **C11** or later, then you should

```
#include <threads.h>
```

However, you may have to wait until your implementation supports it.  § 7.26.1 ¶ 2 of the C11 standard says:

> Implementations that define the macro `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` need not provide this header nor support any of its facilities.

You can check with an `#ifdef` whether your implementation defines it.  At least my GCC does.

For the time being, if you cannot switch to C++, use a third-party threading library like pthreads.

Comment: "*For the time being, if you cannot switch to C++, use a third-party threading library like pthreads.*" Is it because this is a non POSIX OS? In that case woudn't it be appropriate to add an operating system related tag?

Comment: @EOF Did you compile with `-std=c11`? Anyway, the point is that the header is not yet widely supported.

Comment: @iharob If you know one, feel free to edit my question. I don't know Windows.

Comment: Neither do I, I just was wondering about the tags on the question.

Comment: @5gon12eder nope should try that , but i am using cygwin so it should support posix threads, since i have already used files with pthreads.h which runs good.                     problems is only with threads.h

Comment: @EOF Fair enough, so GCC 4.8.4 is non-conforming in that respect. In the current 5.2.0 version, the macro is `#define`d right in the `stdc-predef.h` header which is implicitly `#include`d in every translation unit.

Comment: @avinashvp If pthreads work for you, it's probably the way to go then.

Comment: @5gon12eder yes but i am trying to run a program which has thread.h in it which i have to run , and re-code it in java.

Comment: @5gon12eder Uh, I take that back. Actually 4.8.4 *does* define that macro. It was an older version (4.7.x?) I used a while ago that didn't have the macro.

Answer (score 0):

`thread.h` isn't well defined in the context of c++ standards. If you have a c++11 compliant toolchain, you need to

```
#include <thread>
```

as stated in the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Pre standard toolchains probably need to have the standard specified explicitly using the `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` compiler flags.

---

As you changed your focus to [c](/questions/tagged/c), including c++ headers won't work. You may try [`pthread.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread.h.html).